# Problema com a conexão PDO e mysql_query

Tags: php, html, mysql

Olá, criei o arquivo conexao.php da forma abaixo:

```
   <?
   $conn= new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=site", "root", "");

   $count = ('SELECT * FROM conteudo');
   $stmt = $conn->prepare($count);

   $stmt->execute();
   $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   return $result;
   ?>
```

E aqui eu dou somente o include do arquivo conexao.php?

```
    <?php include "conexao.php"; ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Contentype" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title> Painel Adm. Conteudo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js">
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="texto001" align="left" style=" font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    color:#000000; font-size:12px; float:none; width:<? echo $res['larg_tex001'];?>px; 
    height:<? echo $res['altu_tex001'];?>; position: absolute; left: <? echo $res['hori_tex001'];?>px;
    top: <? echo $res['vert_tex001'];?>px;">

    <img align="left" src="upload/esp_texto.png" /> <?php echo $res['texto001'];?>
    </div>

    <img width="<? echo $res['larg_img001'];?>" height="<? echo $res['altu_img001'];?>" 
    align="left" src="upload/<? echo $res['img001'];?>" style="position: absolute; 
    left: <? echo $res['hori_img001'];?>px; top: <? echo $res['vert_img001'];?>px;" />

    </body>
    </html>
```

Porém estou recebendo as seguintes mensagem abaixo:

[image: Mensagem recebida]

Pergunto aos amigos o que esta faltando para funcionar no WAMPSERVER?
Se os amigos puderem me ajudar a solucionar esse problema, ficarei muito agradecido.
Abraços a todos, e no aguardo de uma ajuda de vocês.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie uma conexão:

```
$conn= new PDO("mysql:host=HOST;dbname=NOMEDOBD", "USUARIO", "SENHA");
```

Crie um statement:

```
$count = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM livro';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($count);
```

e execute o statement:

```
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
return $result;
```

Comment: Esse statement faço no mesmo arquivo da conexao ou crio um outro arquivo?
E  executo onde na minha mysql_query, ou seja na pagina conteudo?
Pois bem eu fiz isso e parou de me enviar as mensagens, porém não me traz mais nada, a página fica totalmente vazia.
Teria como vc. me demostrar como ficaria os aquivos conexao e onde será feita a busca.
Desde já meus agradecimentos e desculpe-me, pois sou muito leigo em PHP e estou tentando aprender.

Comment: Tudo junto nesta mesma ordem, abre conexão cria o statement com a query desejada e executa. Esquece o que fez, você juntou PDO e mysql_query, ambas não coesistem, ou é da forma que fiz `PDO` ou mysql_query.

Comment: Eu editei a minha pergunta com as suas orientações. Seria isso?

Comment: Amigo Ricardo, resolvido, além das suas dicas estarem corretas, eu estava usando <? echo $result ['item']; ?>, ou seja estava esquecendo o 'PHP' depois da ? para buscar os dados.
Cara muito obrigado pela aula.

Comment: @MuriloCabral Disponha!

Answer (score 0):

Você não está fazendo uma conexão com PDO e sim com mysql.

A mensagem diz que a função `mysql_connect()` está depreciada, e que será removida do PHP. O ideal é você utilizar [PDO](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php) ou [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php).

Um exemplo simples de conexão com PDO:

```
$conexao = new PDO("mysql:host=HOST;dbname=NOMEDOBD", "USUARIO", "SENHA");
```

Comment: OK Igor, eu fiz a conexão PDO como me ensinou e como faço o mysql_query, pois agora estou recebendo essas duas  mensagens:

        Deprecated: mysql_query(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\wamp\www\site\conteudo.php on line 3.
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\site\conteudo.php on line 4.